# in ionic 2, how should i store the access token?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, authorization

I want to store access token or authentication in AuthService, but if i initialize them in AuthService.constructor, i can't get the valid token in others Component/Service except I always get it from Storage instead of AuthService, because the offical storage method is asynchronous.

Please forgive my inferior English proficiency & awkwardness ╮(╯▽╰)╭

Comment: You can store them in `localStorage`